# If nested function in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have written the IF nested function as below, but I am getting CC for all the rows. What is wrong here.
=IF(C122="Credit Cards","CC",IF(C122="Investing","INV",IF(C122="Business","BUS",IF(C122="EDB","EDB",IF(C122="Home Loans","HL",IF(C122="Superannuation","SUP",IF(C122="Investing","INV",IF(C122="Brand","BR","PL"))))))))

Comment: does the result become correct after pressing F9?

Comment: No idea.  Pick one row that shouldn't result "CC" and check whether the formula refers to the correct cell.  One thing to try is to replace the `C122="xxx"` to `exact(C122,"xxx")`.

Comment: @ Oliver, Pressing F9 helps.

Comment: Then, you have turned off the auto-calculation option. Check the "Formula" section of Excel Option (File->Option->Formula) and make sure "Automatic" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using long nested IF() functions that are prone to errors, you can create a small table with the data you are comparing with (G3:H10 in the example below) and use INDEX():

[image]

The formula in this example is:

```
=INDEX($H$3:$H$10,MATCH(C13,$G$3:$G$10,0))
```